# iptables configuration to allow specific IP addresses and block the rest

Tags: iptables

I run the following iptables commands through the terminal with the objective of allowing communication only with a set of IP addresses, so far I'm not able to do it and am a bit confused as I'm new to iptables. After running the following curl fails to access the IP address / the domain name. What might be wrong here ?

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP

## allow DNS

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

## allow request to come in from a certain IP address

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 172.217.21.227 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

iptables rules are order dependent, ... if you drop all INPUT first, no further INPUT rules are handled.

Run `sudo iptables -L` to see if your INPUT DROP rule is first.

If so  deleted it `sudo iptables -D INPUT DROP`

and re-add it to the end `sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP`.